# Highcharts y axis thousands separator

Tags: javascript, highcharts, formatting, number-formatting, currency-formatting

How to add a thousands separator to the Y Axis of Highcharts?

This is what I have:

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
```

Comment: Try: `format: '{value:,.0f} €'`

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what [@jfrej suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810931/highcharts-y-axis-thousands-separator#comment29453401_19810931):

- If you're directly formatting an axis, use `{value}` for both [`yAxis`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.format) and [`xAxis`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.format):

  - [Fiddle for `yAxis` format](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/labels-format/)
  - [Fiddle for `xAxis` format](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/PwEnd/)
- If you're formatting a point in a tooltip, you may want to use [`{point.y}` and/or `{point.x}`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat):

  - [Fiddle for `tooltip.pointFormat`](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AYWsW/)
  - [Fiddle for `tooltip.pointFormat` with `valueSuffix` extension](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/pointformat/)
- If you're directly formatting the point label, you may want to use [`{x}` and/or `{y}`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.format):

  - [Fiddle for `plotOptions.series.dataLabels`](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-datalabels-format/), formatting all points
  - [Fiddle for `series.data.dataLabels`](http://jsfiddle.net/bwgwL4e6/), formatting specific point

So, since you're formatting `yAxis`, `{value}` should work as expected:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: '{value:,.0f} €'
    }
}
```

Comment: above solution didn't work for me....I even can't see comma in y-axis of fiddle charts

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari those are just *formatting* fiddle examples provided by Highcharts. You might need to tweak the examples to fulfill your requirements. The last excerpt of my answer suggests the usage tweak related to OP's requirements, which might also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the above solution not working, try to add this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    thousandsSep: ','
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code to format with comma

```
var UNDEFINED;

Highcharts.chart(...
```

...

```
yAxis: {
       labels: {
              formatter: function () {
                     return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, -1, UNDEFINED, ',');
                                     }
               }
       }
```